# Подскажите формулу расчета для прогресс бара, как в FarCry 5

Tags: javascript, c++, математика

Пишу прогресс бар на сайт. Мне нужно рассчитать процент его заполнения. Но, числа там, не систематически идут, типа 2, 4, 8, 10, 12, 14 и т.д.
А всегда возводятся в квадрат. И каждое деление, так сказать "заполняется сложнее" предыдущего.
Вот примерно такую схему нарисовал, что я хочу увидеть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите формулу, это как в FarCry 5. Там каждая шкала заполняется все сложнее и сложнее. Вот мне тоже самое нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно, что именно вам нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если начальное значение будет не 0, а 16, то это логарифмическая шкала, и соответствия

```
процент = Math.log2(значение / 16) * 100 / 6
```

и назад

```
значение = 16 * Math.exp(Math.log(2) * процент * 6 / 100)
```

При желании иметь 0 начальную точку можно как особый случай обрабатывать

Comment: Спасибо бро, сейчас буду тестить :)

Comment: все сработало!!! Спасибо огромное, если не секрет, как эта формула называется, или ты сам придумал? Я для себя, подучить)

Comment: Логарифмическая шкала довольно широко применяется, когда нужно обеспечить большой диапазон. Формулу для конкретного случая можно вывести из общего случая для экспоненциальной функции `y=a*exp(b*x) и x = ln(y/a) / b`, посчитав параметры a и b для нужных пределов шкалы